# :w command in vim moves the cursor to the bottom of the file (NeoVim)

Tags: vim, command, neovim

Every time I use the command :w, to write my file, the cursor gets moved to the bottom of the file; you can imagine how this may be annoying.

cheers.

Comment: It's not `vim`, it's one of your plugins. Disable them one by one to find out which one is the culprit.

Comment: Smells like `BufWritePre`.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, thank you kind sir.